# A closed subset $K$ of $X$ is union of closure of $x$ for all $x \in K$

Tags: general-topology

It may be a silly questions but I really want to know whether the following property is correct or not.

Let $X$ be a topological space. If $K$ is a closed subset of $X$ then 
$$ K = \cup\{ cl\{x\}: x \in K\} .$$
Proof: Obviously,  $K \subseteq \cup\{ cl\{x\}: x \in K\} .$ Since $K$ is closed, for every $x \in K$, $\{x\} \subseteq K$. Therefore, $$\cup\{ cl\{x\}: x \in K\} \subseteq K.$$

Comment: When you wrote $\{x\}\subseteq K$, my guess is that you meant $cl\{x\}\subseteq K$.

Answer (score 1):

Your last 2 sentences should read: "Since $K$ is closed, for every $x \in K$, $cl\{x\} \subseteq K$. Therefore....."